# Django, Error: UserProfile matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I am learning django. Right now, I need to create a Userprofile.

I already created the model which is

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
active = models.BooleanField()
address = models.CharField('Shipping address', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
telephone = models.CharField('Telephone number for shipping', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
steps = models.DecimalField('Steps since creation', max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, null=True)
active = models.BooleanField()

def __str__(self):  
    return "%s's profile" % self.user
```

inside an application called accounting. I already created

```
def create_user_profile(sender, **kwargs):
#When creating a new user, make a profile for him or her.
u = kwargs["instance"]
if not UserProfile.objects.filter(user=u):
    UserProfile(user=u).save()
```

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

So every time a user is created, a profile created automatically. I've already created and verified that the user was created in userprofile table. I also went the shell. I looked for that user which ID is 4. I printed adress for User 4 and I got the address. So I am sure they are linked and working. But when I go to the HTML, i get the error.

Here is the View.

```
    from accounting.models import UserProfile, Charge, Wallet
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

#def userprofile(request, user_id):
def userprofile(request, user_id):


user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
active = user_profile.active
return render_to_response('accounting/templates/userprofile.html', {
    'user_profile': user_profile,   
    'active': active,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'my_profile_app.UserProfile'` in settings.py

Comment: How is that not an answer or solution?

Comment: Yes, I fort got to mention that. I have this in settings AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounting.UserProfile'

Comment: Lott please, help me. Do you know why it is not working? thanks.

Comment: @S.Lott fair enough, point taken - I thought you were commenting on the content more so then the phrasing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
request.user.get_profile()
```

Use:

```
request.user.userprofile
```

After years of Django development, never needed AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE or get_profile(). I don't know what's the advantage of using get_profile() (if any)  but it seems like un-needed hassle.

Actually, I go through even less hassle by using django-annoying's AutoOneToOneField: https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home

More about OneToOne: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#one-to-one-relationships

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work. It gives me the same error. UserProfile matching query does not exist. All of them have a profile, from 2 to 4. I am trying to access number 2, 3 and 4 and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution but, is not working as you told me I am using user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id) instead of request.user.get_profile() and it works. So now I can go to Userprofile and get all the information. But why is not working in the way everytone does?

Comment: Thanks pastylegs for the details. I can see the advantage of get_profile() now it's pretty smart. "user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id) " I'm pretty sure it's improvable - unless you get user_id from the request or something external.

Comment: After reading the code of get_profile(), I did not find any caching superior to what request.user.someOneToOneRelation. It's just caching in an instance variable, which I assume django does by default for OneToOne (e.g. calling request.user.someOneToOneRelation twice won't cause 2 queries would it ?). So I'm lost now, is it useful or not ?

Comment: I think that is why Django recomends to use user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)

Comment: null=False is the default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null